# Generic lambda functions with template parameters

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

```
 #include <utility>
 #include <tuple>

 template < typename T, typename U >
 void h(T, U)
 {
 }

 template < typename... T, typename... U >
 void f(std::tuple < T... >  t, std::tuple < U... >  u)
 {
     auto g = [&] < std::size_t... I > (std::index_sequence < I... >)
              {
                  bool const r[]{((void)h(std::get < I >(t), std::get < I >(u)), false)...};
                  (void)r;
             };
     g(std::index_sequence_for < T... >());
 }

 int main()
 {
     f(std::make_tuple(0L, 0LL), std::make_tuple(0UL, 0ULL));
 }
```

The above compiles with `g++ test_templated_lambda.cpp -o test_templated_lambda -std=c++14`, but doesn't compile with `clang++ test_templated_lambda.cpp -o test_templated_lambda -std=c++14`

I know it is a GCC extension ([Using template parameter in a generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435052/using-template-parameter-in-a-generic-lambda)), but is there some way to do this without writing out `g` as a free function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without some external help; generic lambdas are the only form of template permitted within a function scope, and they cannot be specialized or overloaded (without some external helper, such as [P0051R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0051r1.pdf) `overload`).

It *is* possible to write a compile-time loop by embedding a recursive generic lambda in your function, but (a) you'll have to convert it to fix-point combinator form, and (b) terminating it is seriously ugly:

```
[&](auto&& g) {
  g(g, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>{});
}([&](auto&& g, auto I) {
  h(std::get<I>(t), std::get<I>(u));
  std::get<I + 1 == sizeof...(T)>(std::make_pair(
    [&](auto&& g) { g(g, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I + 1>{}); },
    [](auto&&){}))(g);
});
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79a8fb8141a9e9ba).

You're already using an external helper facility (`std::index_sequence_for`), so why not write another? For example:

```
template<class F, std::size_t... I> auto apply_indexes(F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto g = [&](auto... I)
{
  bool const r[]{((void)h(std::get<I>(t), std::get<I>(u)), false)...};
  (void)r;
};
apply_indexes(g, std::index_sequence_for<T...>());
```

Comment: Helpful.  But I am trying to avoid defining another utility function